# How to count the maximum number of times any node has been visited while traveling through a tree several times?

Tags: algorithm, performance, tree, nodes, graph-algorithm

We travel through a given tree (not binary) several times. How do we calculate the most number of times any node in the tree has been visited?

For example: in the tree:

```
     1
   /   \
 2       3
       /   \
      4     5
```

Suppose we are told to travel 2 times, from 2 to 3, then 5 to 3. The travel paths will be (2->1->3 and 5->3). The maximum number of times a node has been visited is 2 (the node is 3). All travels are independent from each other. A given travel starts from a given node A and ends at B.

How to efficiently travel (if we even need to) in order to calculate that, considering that we have over 50,000 nodes and 75,000 paths to cover (like 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 in the example)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? if this is a tree with pointers from parent to child and you started at 2 how do you go to 3? if this is a bidrectional relation what was the initial goal? to go from 2 to 4? if so how do you visit 3 twice?

Comment: The edges are bidirectional. We have a list of all edges : {(1,2),(1,3),(3,4),(3,5))
The goal is just to travel from node _i_ to node _j_ (via shortest distance) several times (value of _i_ and _j_ possibly varying each time) and to find the maximum number of times any node has been visited. In the travel path in above example, you can see 3 is mentioned twice (from two individual travels), no other node has been visited more than twice, so the answer is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying, the answer is the amount of children that node has...

Also in your example, going off what you have said, both 1 and 3 are visited the most.

In your example each node is only going to get visited once. The only way you could get multiple visits to one node would be with a tree like:

```
          1     3
            \ /
             2
```

Edit:: the most efficient way of traversing is if you have a perfect binary tre

```
   4
 2   6
1 3 5 7
```

Where the max depth is number of ((log base 2 of (number of nodes + 1)) + 1) rounded down

Comment: That's not what I meant. We aren't doing the typical tree traversal here. We choose the shortest path from node A to node B. Path for 2 to 3 is: 2->1->3, then path for 3 to 4 (independent of previous travel) is: 3->4.

Only once does 1 appear in the path. So it has been visited once.

Comment: The tree isn't binary. And a given travel (out of 74,999 other travels) starts from one node and ends the given another. I guess I'll add all this in original question. I ain't good at explanations.

Comment: Are you saying from ANY node to ANY other node, you want to be able to work out the shortest distance? If so, and your tree is ordered, you can work it out. If it is not ordered, you are going to have to traverse the tree to find out.

Comment: Yes, I need to work out the shortest distance. No, the tree isn't ordered. Also the constraints, don't allow me to traverse through the tree for each travel. In the worst case, we have 75k*50k operations just in traversing. Is there any way we can use past travel data to reduce calculations for further travels? I have an intuition prefix sums may help somehow but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the travel count of each node separately?

1. Maintain a `HashMap<Node, long>` keeping track of how many times each node has been visited.
2. Then maintain a `TreeMap<long, List<Node>>` that is keyed on count and contains the list of node whose count it is representing.

This way, the TreeMap's first would contain all the nodes that have the highest count, because there can definitely be more than one node with that highest visit count.

All you now need to do is add bookkeeping code for properly updating the two maps whenever a node is visited as part of a tree traversal.

Comment: The is definitely doable but the travel itself is very inefficient. In the worst case, 3.75 billion operations happen just while traveling.
Is there any way we can use past travel data to reduce calculations for further travels? Also, is traveling necessary to calculate maximum visits?  I have an intuition prefix sums may help somehow but I don't know how.

Comment: @PappuKhan: In the solution given above, you don't have to travel. You use the TreeMap to get the most traveled nodes list in O(1). The extra work that you do is this: while you are traversing the nodes during the regular work, you also update the two maps.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Your question states you want to store number of node visits. What you really want though is an efficient traversal strategy.

You have options here. Since the edges are bi-directional the best strategy IMO would be a bi-directional search.

But the search strategy itself is a toss up.

Consider a slightly more elaborate tree as 
`1 -> 2,3,4; 2 -> 5,6,7; 3->8,9; 4->10,11; 10 -> 12,13`. If you have an efficient path from `5` to `4` It doesn't mean you can just start from there to find an efficient path from `5` to `13` because you don;t `13` comes under `4` ***unless*** you've already found an efficient path from `4` to `13`.

So I would suggest memoizing your traversals in a dictionary of the form `<Node Pair>: [Traversal list]`

Where you start at a target node and perform a Breadth first search. and each time you visit a node, examine your memoization structure if there exists a an entry for `<curnode,targetnode>` in the dictionary. If there exists an entry, you are done. If not proceed to the current node's sibling or child.

**CAVEAT: THIS IS UNDER THE ASSUMPTION THAT ALL NODES HAVE ONLY 1 PARENT AND CYCLES DON'T HAPPEN**

Comment: You got my question right. I'm sorry I'm bad at explaining.

I thought of the exact same method as you suggest here, but there's one more problem. Suppose no node in the tree has more than one child. In case of a tree with 50000 nodes in a single line and all 75000 travels involving path from the root node to the leaf node, we'll traverse throughout tree for the first time. In the second travel, memo will return an existing path, but we still would have to update the count of visits on all the nodes involved, ultimately leading to 50k operations in all 75k travels still. How to avoid that?

Comment: so you want to figure out which node is part of most traversals?

Comment: No. I need to find the maximum number of traversals any node in the tree has been a part of. Knowing which node accomplishes this is not necessary.

Comment: In that case think about your example. If there 50k nodes with degree 2(save the first and last) and 75k desired traversals from the first node to the last. Then in the worst case you get a path 50k long 75k times. **There is no way for you to not perform 50k operations everytime**. The only think you can do to optimize is to ensure that the cost of these operations if ~= 0 (but not quite 0).

Answer (score 0):

I think people are miss understanding the question. He/she wants to ask which node is visited max number of times given x number of travel. So from his tree edges are {(2-1)(1-3)(3-4),(3-5)} now for example we are traveling in following paths{(1,5), (2,4), (1,3), (1,2), (1,3), (4,5)}. So this example 3 visited 5 times, 1 visited 4 times and so on.
Since it is a tree there is only one path exist from one node to another. Find paths for all combination of nodes in DP way and store it. 
Then count for each visit. I know there is more efficient way for counting but cannot think of it right now.